# Who is Rabbi Shmuel ben Elqanah Mi-Altona?

Tags: rabbis, responsa

He wrote Meqom Shmouel (מקום שמואל), a book of Responsa that contains a lot of materials and discussions from the Rishonim, especially the Rambam. I assume that this is the Aharonim period, the pdf copy I have (from hebrewbooks) indicates the date 1738 (Altona). However he may have lived earlier. I found a [brief reference](https://groups.jewishgen.org/g/main/topic/70493871#:%7E:text=Among%20the%20prominent%20Jews%20of%20Courland%20in%20the%20eighteenth%20century%20were%20the%20%0Afollowing%3A%20Rabbi%20Samuel%20ben%20Elkanah%20of%20the%20Teomin%20family%2C%20author%20of%20%E2%80%9CMekom%20%0AShemuel%E2%80%9D%20Altona%2C%201722.%20%20He%20was%20born%20at%20Altona%2C%20and%20officiated%20%20as%20rabbi%20at%20%0AMitau%2C%20where%20he%20died%20in%201742.) in the Jewish Encyclopedia that he was born in Altona, lived in the 18th century and was a rabbi in Mitau, Latvia. Apart from this, I do not have any other personal information. Judging by the very little I gathered from his writings (originally I needed just one responsum of his), he had a vast knowledge of Talmud and many other rabbinic sources. Is he related to other well-known Jewish figures? How well-known or unknown was/is his work?

Comment: From the intro to the reprint of his book: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1044&st=&pgnum=3: 
רבינו המחבר נולד לאביו מוהר"ר אלקנה ז"ל והיה מילידי העיירות המפוארות דק"ק אלטונא והאמבורג ונראה מתשובותיו שבימי חורפו למד אצל הגאון הגדול רשכבה"ג מוהר"ר אברהם ברודא זצללה"ה וגם למד אצל הגאונים המפורסמים אבדק"ק אה"ו, הגאון הגדול בעל שו"ת חכם צבי, והגאון הגדול מוהר"ר משה רוטנבורג זצללה"ה. גם זכה לבן גדול בתורה מוהר"ר פסח ז"ל שחיבר ספר "קמח פסח" לתרץ קושית המהרש"א על פירוש רש"י ותוס', ויש שם כמה שו"ת מאביו.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up.